# Mouse pointer hard to see in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, mouse-cursor

The normal desktop mouse pointer is a white arrowhead. It changes to a faint *I* beam when it moves over an active mate-terminal.

I am using the Mate desktop 1.20.4 in Debian "buster". If I move the mouse rapidly within the terminal window, the *I* beam becomes invisible.

I am hoping that the shape and colour of the mouse pointer can be configured. But so far I have found no configuration information for the mate-terminal. The mouse pointer is not mentioned in dconf, and there is no terminal related file in /home/.conf/mate/

The best solution would be for the mouse pointer to remain unchanged. One suggestion -  press the Alt key - for the Mac does not work on my PC.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165721/changing-the-mouse-pointer-in-mate

Comment: Yes, Control Center>Appearance>Pointer can change the size of the pointer, but the shape still changes from arrowhead to I beam.  I suspect that this behaviour is not under Mate control.

Comment: I totally agree with you and I'm looking for the solution of the problem as well. Did you find any?

Comment: Sorry, I have not found a solution to this and have resorted to changing the background color of the terminal to get better contrast. Helps a little bit